# Dagger Hilt Android gives Error : method getActivityFactory in class DefaultViewModelFactories cannot be applied to given types

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I am working on a project where I have implemented Dagger Hilt + Retrofit + Coroutine.

But after a new update of dependencies of dagger hilt, the project is not able to run.

I am getting this error for the activities and fragments in which I have implemented Dagger and Viewmodels with Dependency Injection. Earlier before the dependency update, it was working fine.

Here is the screenshot for the same:

[image]

Here is the class that is created by Dagger and that has the error:

[image]

If anyone has faced this same issue. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
I have followed [this](https://rahul9650ray.medium.com/dagger-hilt-retrofit-coroutines-9e8af89500ab) tutorial. This tutorial is also working fine for me, but I am getting the above errors after updating the dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I find out what was the problem.

The problem is in the official documentation of Dagger Hilt [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack)

See the screenshot of that document below.

[image]

The problem is in the code of documentation. It's really frustrating why they don't update their official documentation!!! Let it be.......

We have to change

FROM

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mainRepository: MainRepository
) : ViewModel() {
```

TO

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val mainRepository: MainRepository
) : ViewModel(), LifecycleObserver {
```

They have missed `LifecycleObserver` and because of that, I was facing errors.

Not only this,

You should also note that following dependency's version should also be the same.

in App Level Gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.35.1"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.35.1"
```

in Project Level Gradle:

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35.1"
```

Comment: many many thanks. exactly the same problem I faced

Comment: I had same issue. It was because different library version as you told. Worked it without adding LifecycleObserver in the viewModel

Answer (score -1):

dependency version for project level and module level must be same .